# Sum of next two and three rows based on group by

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below which is basically list of player and points he has scored in his innings.
I have around 50,000 rows in this data frame and data frame is sorted based on the date

```
PLAYER_CODE PLAYER_RUNS  MATCH_ID
123          10          1
112          5           1
123          15          2
112          10          2 
112          24          3
123          10          3
123          5           4
```

I need to add new columns that is PREV_TWO & PREV_THREE which should be sum of his last two inning and three innings thus giving me following DF

```
PLAYER_CODE PLAYER_RUNS  PREV_TWO  PREV_THREE
123          10          25        30  
112          5           34        34
123          15          15        15
112          10          24        24
112          24          0         0
123          10          5         5
123          5           0         0
```

I have come up with following code to do the same:

```
playerList = dataFrame['PLAYER_CODE'].unique().tolist()
print(len(playerList) , " Players found in dataframe")

for playerCode in playerList:
    #CREATE A PLAYER SPECIFIC DF TO LOOP AROUND THE ROWS
    playerDF = dataFrame[dataFrame['PLAYER_CODE'] == playerCode]
    playerRows = len(playerDF.index)

    i = 0
    for row in playerDF.itertuples(): #LOOP AROUND 
        j = i + 3 #TO GET THE 2-3 ROW
        x = i + 4 #TO GET THE 2-4 ROW
        #GET THE MATCH ID OF CURRENT ROW WILL BE USED TO IDENTIFY UNIQUE ROW TO UPDATE
        playerMatchId = playerDF.iloc[i]['PLAYER_MATCH_ID']
        #SUM THE WICKETS
        sumoflasttwo = playerDF.iloc[i+1:j]['PLAYER_RUNS'].sum()
        sumoflastthree = playerDF.iloc[i+1:x]['PLAYER_RUNS'].sum()

         #UPDATE THE MAIN DATA FRAME
        dataFrame.loc[(dataFrame['PLAYER_MATCH_ID'] == playerMatchId) & 
                      (dataFrame['PLAYER_CODE'] == playerCode),'LAST_TWO_AVG'] = sumoflasttwo

        dataFrame.loc[(dataFrame['PLAYER_MATCH_ID'] == playerMatchId) & 
                      (dataFrame['PLAYER_CODE'] == playerCode),'LAST_THREE_AVG'] = sumoflastthree
        i = i+1
```

This approach works but it is really slow. I am pretty sure that there would be a way to do this without loop but I am not aware for it.
Is there a way to do it without looping through the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why `PLAYER_MATCH_ID` is in descending order, but `PREVX` columns refer to the next match ids. This made it a lot more confusing when troubleshooting the dataset, but I figured it out!

First, acquire the groups of dataframes in descending order based on `PLAYER_MATCH_ID` (to be able to use the rolling function).

```
player_List = dataFrame['PLAYER_CODE'].unique().tolist()
groups = [dataFrame.groupby('PLAYER_CODE').get_group(i) for i in player_List]
groups = [i.sort_values('PLAYER_MATCH_ID', ascending = False) for i in groups]
```

Next, use the `rolling` function to get the values based on the `PLAYER_MATCH_ID`

```
dfs2 = [i['PLAYER_RUNS'].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 2).sum()
        .shift(1).fillna(0) for i in groups]
dfs3 = [i['PLAYER_RUNS'].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3)
        .sum().shift(1).fillna(0) for i in groups]
```

Then, define a function to add the columns (as I presume you will have more than 2 dataframes).

```
def add_columns(dat, dfs2, dfs3):
    dat['PREV_TWO'] = dfs2
    dat['PREV_THREE'] = dfs3
    return dat
```

Finally we can acquire the final dataframes and merge them.

```
from functools import reduce 

final_dfs = [add_columns(groups[i], dfs2[i], 
             dfs3[i]).sort_values('PLAYER_MATCH_ID') for i in range(len(groups))]

# Final dataframe will be in order of PLAYER_CODE and sorted by PLAYER_MATCH_ID
reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, how = 'outer'), final_dfs)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions. That code can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the code it works but the execution time is no good. it takes twice as long as the original code. I was looking for something that can reduce the execution time.

Comment: For me it took about half the time. I tested it and verified using the timeit function. Are you sure it takes twice as long?
My code: 11.4 ms ± 218 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each);
Original code: 27.1 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: My actual data frame is huge with around 25-30 columns but the calculations need to be done on the columns I mentioned in the question. Could that be the reason? I will check more and try to find which part is taking most time. I am suspecting probably merge.

Comment: That is probably true. Let's try to build a suitable hybrid of the code.